# JIRA Issue Navigator: how to search who was the last to update an issue?

Tags: jira

In Jira, in Issue Navigator, I want to see who was the last person to update an issue. Is there a field that does this?

I have tried "Updated" which shows the time of the last update. I want to know who did the update.

Comment: Isnt the `History`'s tab visible / enabled for you? - you should be able to see all chronological changes therein.

Comment: Yes, but then I need to go to each issue separately.

Comment: good question!!

Answer (score 2):

Within the **Issue navigator** you are having additional flexibility with *Advanced Search*, but it doesn't search through the history of changes. The search criteria and [complete list of supported column names could be found in their manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html) (see the "column List of Fields" to the right).

Unfortunately JIRA doesn't support the column you are looking for out of the box. The closest fields, probably could be `Assignee`, `Updated`, `Last viewed`, but it's not what you are looking for. [Usage of JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html#Advancedsearching-ConstructingJQLqueries) doesn't bring any additional use here, as it operates with the same set of supported fields and the same representation grid.

---

You can see chronological changes in the issue details itself, there would be tabs called `history` and `activity`, it's what you are looking for. It will show you all the chronological changes, who made, at what time, and what.

There's the [help section](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/viewing-an-issue-s-change-history-720416460.html) as well at atlassian website.

Comment: That would mean I need to click into each issue separately. I want a view with all of the issues.

Comment: @user1413, first of all, it's not fair from your side to down-vote, as you questioned the way it's not clear to anyone, that you wanted to avoid the clicking every issue. I will update my answer then.

Comment: Agree with @Farside the user1413 is unable to articulate or clearly express their question - also re-iterating one-liners that dont elaborate the matter or help near a solution for them-self.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still wondering how to do this without addons, Atlassian [committed to implementing this after 15 years](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-1973).